# jQuery Mobile output issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, each

I'm working with jQuery mobile and I need to create a list of collapsible (accordion) items. My issue is that the main collapsible items are being nested within each other. I need the groups separate, like this:

[ COLLAPSIBLE ONE ]
   (image)
   Name A
   linkA1
   linkA2

[ COLLAPSIBLE TWO ]
   (image)
   Name B
   linkB1
   linkB2

   (image)
   Name C
   linkC1
   linkC2

...

The collapsible lists should looked stacked, as shown in [their API page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html)

Here is what I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/pggJm/1/

**output.json**

```
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "venue": "COLLAPSIBLE ONE",
            "event": [
                {
                    "img": "imgA.jpg",
                    "name": "Name A",
                    "location": "loc A",
                    "desc": "desc A",
                    "link1": "linkA1.html",
                    "link2": "linkA2.html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "venue": "COLLAPSIBLE TWO",
            "event": [
                {
                    "img": "imgB.jpg",
                    "name": "Name B",
                    "location": "loc B",
                    "desc": "desc B",
                    "link1": "linkB1.html",
                    "link2": "linkB2.html"
                },
                {
                    "img": "imgC.jpg",
                    "name": "Name C",
                    "location": "loc C",
                    "desc": "desc C",
                    "link1": "linkC1.html",
                    "link2": "linkC2.html"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**main.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "output.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var html2 = [];
        $.each(data.actions, function(i, entry) {
                html2.push('<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="d" data-inset="false">')
                html2.push('<h4>'+this.venue+'</h4>');      

           $.each(this.event, function() {
                html2.push('<img src="'+this.img+'" class="img_border" alt="'+this.img+'"/>');
                html2.push('<p>'+this.name+'</p>');
                html2.push('<p>'+this.location+'</p>');
                html2.push('<a href="'+this.link1+'" target="_blank" data-role="button">Lorem</a>');
                html2.push('<a class="external" href="'+this.link2+'" target="_blank" data-role="button">Ipsum</a>');
            });
        });

        $('#cat2').append( html2.join('') ).trigger( "create" );
    } // end success
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are not closing the div for each collapsible.  So the second div ends up in the first and the third ends up in the second.
You need to add the following line to the end of the $.each loop:

```
html2.push('</div>');
```

I have updated the fiddle to reflect this.